# Wordpress Login / SSL = Code Question

Tags: login, ssl

i would be thankful if someone can explain the following code, from wp-login.php (the first few lines of the file):

```
 // Redirect to https login if forced to use SSL
    if ( force_ssl_admin() && ! is_ssl() ) {
        if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {
            wp_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
            exit();
        } else {
            wp_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
            exit();
        }
    }
```

As far as I know, the $_SERVER[RQUEST_URI] can only contain absolute paths, like /wordpress/mapage/?foo=bar. Why is  it checked on a protocoll/scheme?

And why are there two cases (false/true) what, do they do exactly. Espeically the first one. The second one is the same, I would have written the function using https + Host + URI

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This part of code was introduced as whole block, together with a bunch of other stuff, quite a few years ago. See [changeset 8069 in trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/8069).

While there is no clear mention in PHP docs, apparently in specific configurations the value *might* be a full URL with protocol. See for example [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returns full URL instead of path to script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200070/serverrequest-uri-returns-full-url-instead-of-path-to-script) question on Stack Overflow.

The two cases are because the code to form secure URL is different, conditional on that possible difference in input.